# Ubuntu Kernel Compilation?

Tags: kernel

I'm trying to compile and install kernel 3.13.1 on ubuntu 13.10 using following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc 
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev 
cd Downloads/ 
sudo tar -xvf linux-3.0.tar.bz2 -C /usr/src/ 
cd /usr/src/linux-3.0/ 
sudo make menuconfig 
sudo make oldconfig 
sudo make
```

After the last command it gets compiled, but when I try to install that using the command:

```
sudo make modules_install install
```

is gives an error saying:

> file 'include/config/auto.cnfig.cmd' has modification time 3.6e+04 sec in future
>   cannot stat /usr/src/linux/modules.builtin no such file or directory exist

Can anyone help me out installing that?

Comment: Why are you building Kernel 3.0?

Comment: Install `build-essential`, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using make you need to keep your time in sync, because make decides to build particular target based on creation/modification time. You might have partition mounted with some time related options like `noatime`.